# hadoop mapreduce error

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hadoop-plugins

I am facing some ERROR when i am runnig hadoop on map reduce environment in eclipse error,

An internal error occurred during:"Refresh DFS Children".

```
org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ssh2.CVSSSH2Plugin.get PreferenceStore()Lorg /eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore.
```

Answer (score 0):

can you specify which version of hadoop, OS name, java version you are using?

For now, try to follow these steps, which resolved this issue for me:

1. In the "MapReduce Servers" pane - Delete the hadoop server.
2. Re-establish a MapReduce Server and validation through
3. you can continue to use